# What does the phrase "What you failed to take into account" mean?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, synonyms

Have you ever made a bad decision?
**In hindsight, it’s plain to see what you failed to take into account.**

What does this phrase mean?

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with? The phrase "what you failed to take into account" is the *object* of the verb "see". Simpler sentences are "I see **what you did**" and then "I see **what you did not do**" and so on.

Comment: i don't understand the whole bold part.I don't get the meaning.

Comment: You'll have to be more explicit. Do you undertstand what "in hindsight" means?

Comment: yes I understand that part and I know It's plain to see means It's obvious, but it's obvious what?

Comment: "To take into account" means "to consider". If you "fail to do sth" it means you "did not do sth." So it has now become obvious what you did not consider. For example (without context), "Looking back, it is obvious that you overlooked XXX."

Answer (score 1):

"Take into account" is an idiom meaning "consider" or "think about".  There are details of the problem you failed to consider, and that led to your bad decision.

(I'll note that this meaning isn't obvious from the common dictionary definitions of "account", but if you Google `take into account meaning` you will find some helpful definitions.)

Answer (score 0):

"take into account" means "factor in"

Answer (score -3):

> Oxford Dictionary
>
> **Account**
>
> noun: account; plural noun: accounts
>
> 1. a report or description of an event or experience.
> 2. a record or statement of financial expenditure and receipts relating to a particular period or purpose.
> 3. an arrangement by which a body holds funds on behalf of a client or supplies goods or services to the client on credit.
> 4. an arrangement by which a user is given personalized access to a computer, website, or application, typically by entering a username
>      and password.
> 5. importance.

Definition #1 of account is the relevant use case here.

To "take into" is a term which in this context means to add data to a data set, which is the account.

So, when you say you failed to take something into account, you are saying that you failed to include a piece of (typically important) information into how you would describe the event or experience.  When you use this expression you are saying that you failed to evaluate the situation properly because your own perspective, interpretation, or knowledge was incomplete without the thing you did not take in.